# Retrieve mysql data in javascript var

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to retrieve data from mysql using PHP in Javascript Var. The current data is static data, i need to make them dynamic by retriving them from mysql db without changing the format. Basically i need to get CURRENCIES, WEBUY, WESELL INVBUY, INVSELL from mysql. Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currencies={};
            currencies['USD'] = {WEBUY: 1.0965, WESELL: 1.1235, INVBUY: 0.912, INVSELL: 0.8901};
            currencies['AED'] = {WEBUY: 0.285, WESELL: 0.3195, INVBUY: 3.50877, INVSELL: 3.12989};
            currencies['ARS'] = {WEBUY: 0.1175, WESELL: 0.1525, INVBUY: 8.51064, INVSELL: 6.55738};
            currencies['AUD'] = {WEBUY: 0.98, WESELL: 1.03, INVBUY: 1.02041, INVSELL: 0.97087};
            currencies['BBD'] = {WEBUY: 0.495, WESELL: 0.5995, INVBUY: 2.0202, INVSELL: 1.66806};
            currencies['BMD'] = {WEBUY: 0.95, WESELL: 1.145, INVBUY: 1.05263, INVSELL: 0.87336};
            currencies['BRL'] = {WEBUY: 0.445, WESELL: 0.4895, INVBUY: 2.24719, INVSELL: 2.0429};
            currencies['BSD'] = {WEBUY: 0.84, WESELL: 1.1095, INVBUY: 1.19048, INVSELL: 0.90131};
            currencies['BWP'] = {WEBUY: 0.1, WESELL: 0.1425, INVBUY: 10, INVSELL: 7.01754};
        </script>
```

Comment: what is your issue , how far have u done anything ? here no one will do it from scratch for you !

Answer (score 0):

Here two hints.

First you can use the the StdClass, to build your object.

```
$currency = new StdClass;
$currency->webuy = $valuewebuy;
$currency->wesell = $valuewesell;
//continue
```

Then, you can create an associative array

```
$myarray[$thecurrency] = $currency;
```

In the end, just use `json_encode($myarray)` to get your json.

Here the concept, so just add some loop with your fetched data, and you are done !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you're wanting to have PHP code emit Javascript which will then be embedded into the HTML page delivered to the browser?

This is not too difficult, it is a straightforward programming problem in PHP. It is not hard to issue a `mysql_query()` to get the result set you want out of your database, and then iterate across the return values from `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which will give you an associative array for each row in the query result set.

From there you simply have to issue the right echo or printf commands so that your script emits valid Javascript code.

The other way to do this is with AJAX which is more involved... you could keep the Javascript code static, but (drastically) rewrite it so that it issues requests back to the server which responds with JSON or XML objects, which could then be converted to data structures in your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway i figured it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currencies={}; 
<?php 
  $db=mysql_connect('localhost','dbuser','pass') or die('Error connecting to the server'); 
  mysql_select_db('db') or die('Error selecting database'); 
  $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM rates2') or die ('Error performing query'); 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
?> 
currencies['<?php echo ''.$row['code'].''?>'] = {WEBUY: <?php echo ''.$row['webuy'].''?>, WESELL: <?php echo ''.$row['wesell'].''?>, INVBUY: <?php echo ''.$row['invbuy'].''?>, INVSELL: <?php echo ''.$row['invsell'].''?>}; 
<?php 
  } 
?>
```